# Set border outside the bounds of UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView in my XIB file. Size is 50x50.

In the view code I have the following:

```
self.pic.layer.borderColor = _a_color_;
self.pic.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
self.pic.layer.shadowColor = _a_color_;
self.pic.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.30f;
self.pic.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f);
self.pic.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0f;
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.pic.bounds];
self.pic.layer.shadowPath = path.CGPath;
```

My problem is that the border is drawn inside the image and the problem with this, is that
I am loosing 6 (2x3.0) points from my image (in both dimensions).

What is the correct way to set the border outside the bounds of the image?

A second option would be to shrink the image (by 2xborderWidth). How can be done?

Comment: Have you considered adding a `CALayer` as border, to your view, and setting it's `masksToBounds`/`clipsToBounds` to `NO`? You can nest it inside a slightly larger `UIView`, but `CALayer`s are lighter than `UIView`s.

Comment: **Add** a layer to your view, instead of replacing it's own layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to draw your image view on another view that has slightly bigger frame than you image view, and set desired color to that view's background color. In your case, background view should be {56,56} in size, and your image view should be centered on that view. And, don't forget to remove layer manipulations. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

This will help you :)

```
// setting ImageViewBorder Width, here i used 5.0f

self.yourImageView.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;

// setting ImageViewBorder Color 

self.yourImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightTextColor].CGColor;
```

Comment: This does not set the border outside the image view but inside.